# Perl Expression for negate a group

Tags: php, regex, perl, preg-match

I have this log:

```
The Foo bar, and Bar foo needs to Foo 
The Bar of Bar foo Bar Foo Foo
Bar bar The Bar of Foo other Foo Bar
```

And I want to create a perl expresion that only select words that are not Foo nor Bar. The result log must be:

```
The bar, and foo needs to
The of foo
The of other
```

I have this one:

```
^(Foo|Bar)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the comments correctly, what you want is to capture all the words that are not `Foo` or `Bar`, and then presumably print them somehow. This would be one way to do such a thing:

```
/(?<!\S)(?!Foo|Bar)\S+(?!\S)/g
```

It is less complicated than it looks, here's the annotated version:

```
/
    (?<!\S)            # match cannot be preceded by non-whitespace
    (?!Foo|Bar)(\S+)   # capture non-whitespace that is not Foo|Bar
    (?!\S)             # match cannot be followed by non-whitespace
/gx                    # match globally and ignore whitespace in regex
```

Note that `/x` is just there so I can use comments and newlines inside the regex.

The start and end pieces of this regex is our boundary anchors. We use these to make sure we do not get partial matches. They are negative look-around assertions, and replacements for the somewhat simpler `\b` word boundary assertion. It was not possible to use `\b` here though, because you have a comma character in your string. The reason we use `(?!\S)` instead of `\s` is that while they both match whitespace, the latter does not match start/end of string.

Because we have assured ourselves we cannot get partial matches, we can now use a simple alternation inside our anchors with another negative lookahead assertion. I.e. `(?!Foo|Bar)`. If that does not match, we capture the string with `(\S+)`.

Here is the test case I created for this problem:

```
perl -nlwe 'push @a, [/(?<!\S)(?!Foo|Bar)(\S+)(?!\S)/g] }{ print "@$_" for @a'
The Foo bar, and Bar foo needs to Foo
The Bar of Bar foo Bar Foo Foo
Bar bar The Bar of Foo other Foo Bar
^Z
The bar, and foo needs to
The of foo
bar The of other
```

This uses our regex to capture strings from `$_` (the input) and push them onto the `@a` array inside array references. After the input is done (after the eskimo operator `}{`), we print the interpolated array references to add spaces. `"@$_"` is equivalent to `join " ", @$_` in this case.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox You were the one who managed to get him to say it, so +1 to you for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to *remove* values from the string, a substitution would work:

```
my $str = <<EOS;
    The Foo bar, and Bar foo needs to Foo
    The Bar of Bar foo Bar Foo Foo
    Bar bar The Bar of Foo other Foo Bar
EOS
$str =~ s/(?:Foo|Bar) ?//g;
print $str;

>>>The bar, and foo needs to
   The of foo
   bar The of other
```

Note that the last "bar" (lowercase) is still in there; I'm assuming that was a mistake in your post.

Comment: I need just the regular expresion with in the negate form. something like (Foo|Bar) but with the negation syntax. Noot using !~

Comment: @ingcarlos - Then please revise your question to explain what it actually is that you're looking for. I think you're saying you want a regexp that matches all words in the string that aren't Foo or Bar (in which case this isn't really a Perl question, but a general PCRE question).

Comment: I know that your substitution will work like a charm, but I need an expresion also.